How to compare 2 images to see if they are the same image using C# and jquery?
Using VS2022, C#, Blazor and jquery the code first loads a "C:\Images\defaultImage.png" into a canvas region in the page:
 <canvas id="CanvasId" @ref="canvasElement"></canvas>

 await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("loadImageOnCanvas", "CanvasId", "/scripts/defaultImage.png");

This image is then saved into a database. At another day, the user retrieves the image from the db and loads it in the canvas. At this point, after the image is loaded from the db, the user needs to know if this image is still the same picture as the defaultImage.png, (that is stored in the C: driver), or if the defaultImage.png has been changed/replaced.
NOTE: It is a simple image in black and white and only 27KB size 241px x 154px.
To check it, I use the code below but when both are compared
they are never equal. The one from the canvas is always a bit bigger in size, around 1k.
// Retrieve the image that was loaded on canvas
var canvasImage = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("captureCanvasImage", "CanvasId");
canvasImage = canvasImage.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", String.Empty);
               
// byte[27980]
byte[] imageOnCanvas_Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(canvasImage);
    
// byte[26978]
byte[] defaultImage_Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("wwwroot/scripts/defaultImage.png");
                    
// Compare as string returns FALSE  
var result = canvasImage == Convert.ToBase64String(defaultImage_Bytes);
                     
// Compare byte arrays returns FALSE
var result2 = imageOnCanvas_Bytes.SequenceEqual(defaultImage_Bytes);


Define "same" for your context.  The obvious solution for an unchanging image would be to load it onto a canvas, and then save it to your DB as a base64 string, then compare the 2 strings.

I am just going by the guidelines:
When saving images to a SQL Server database in a C# application, using a byte array is generally better than using a string. Here are the reasons: Efficiency, Performance and Storage

A .png file isn't a bitmap.  It's a compressed bitmap with embedded metada, all of which you're loading when you read the file.  You need to create an in-memory bitmap from it, and convert it to base64 before comparing.  But I'm curious-- what is your site doing, that you need to check in this way?  Why can't you just log changes when they're made, or check the timestamp on the files, etc?

As for efficiency, performance, and storage: we regularly transmit images that are megabytes in size, or stream many hundreds of kilobytes per second in video.  Trying to save the compressed amount of a 27KB bitmap (i.e. even less than 27KB) is working hard to solve a problem that doesn't matter, to be blunt.

@Ben Junior, Is there any progress on the issue?

@Bennyboy1973 It is because when one or more of these changes in the image are eventually removed, and the image becomes equal to the default one again, I don't want it to be redundantly stored in the db. There are hundreds(up to thousands) of rows. (I upvoted your comments)

You could try checking the actual Image data.
public static bool IsImageSame(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{            
//we're only concerned with reading the image data.
ImageLockMode mode = ImageLockMode.ReadOnly;
Rectangle view1 = default;
Rectangle view2 = default;

try
{                
    view1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
    view2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height);

}
catch (Exception)
{
    //an error here can mean a bitmap is null or has been disposed.
    return false;
}

//check the PixelFormats are the same if not return Undefined
PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Undefined;
if(bmp1.PixelFormat == bmp2.PixelFormat) 
{
    format = bmp1.PixelFormat;
}

//if the format is undefined then our formats are different, return false
if (format == PixelFormat.Undefined) 
{ 
    return false; 
}
           
//get the BitmapData for our bitmaps
BitmapData bmp1Data = bmp1.LockBits(view1, mode, format);
BitmapData bmp2Data = bmp2.LockBits(view2, mode, format);

//create byte[] values for the actual color data
byte[] bmp1Buffer = new byte[bmp1Data.Stride * bmp1Data.Height];
byte[] bmp2Buffer = new byte[bmp2Data.Stride * bmp2Data.Height];

//copy the color data to our arrays
Marshal.Copy(bmp1Data.Scan0, bmp1Buffer, 0, bmp1Buffer.Length);
Marshal.Copy(bmp2Data.Scan0, bmp2Buffer, 0, bmp2Buffer.Length);

//unlock the bitmaps and return result
bmp1.UnlockBits(bmp1Data);
bmp2.UnlockBits(bmp2Data);

return bmp1Buffer.SequenceEqual(bmp2Buffer);

}

If you want to compare pixel values you probably want to extract the actual pixel data, and not just compare the file-bytes. Image files may change if it is resaved, even if the pixels is identical. Not sure if this is your actual problem, but it might be worth a try.
To get the pixel data you should be able to use something like this:
var decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(
    myStream,
    BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
var frame = decoder.Frames[0];
var width = frame.PixelWidth;
var height = frame.PixelHeight;

var bytesPerPixel = frame.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
var stride = bytesPerPixel * width;
while (stride % 4 != 0) stride++; // Make stride an even multiple of four
var data = new byte[stride * height];
frame.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);

Where myStream is either a file stream or memory stream containing the bytes for the file.
This should handle any changes to metadata in the file, but will not handle any change to the actual pixels. If you need to handle changes things will quickly get complicated. There are several possible similarity metrics, but it is nor really possible to recommend anything without understanding the type of changes you need to handle.
A possibly better approach is to attach some kind of versioning data to the image to track changes, but I don't know enough about Blazor, nor your use case, to recommend anything specific.

I rewrote the question to clarify the issue more effectively

@JonasH This is, for sure, the problem.  No question about it.

Comparing two images in this context can be tricky and maybe it can get complex overtime.
If you are handling the modification events (uploading a new image to the canvas, click or drag event, etc...), you can workaround all of this by defining a history of changes, meaning each event you're concerned to handle should add a new element to a List<string> ChangeHistory for example. Thus, an image is edited in the canvas only if ChangeHistory has elements.
this separates the concern of "what has been modified" from "it has been modified", and also (slightly for your situation) improves the overall performance without needing to make comparisons.
Visual Studio itself uses a similar approach for determining if it should show you the (*) on your class name tab if it's been modified. for example, if you type in a character in your code, VS automatically shows the asterisk, the asterisk won't go away if you simply delete the character but only if you click in Undo (or ctrl+Z). That's because the VS does not compare, but holds a history of modification events.
HTH.
